# Google Embed API Demo window.google.load is not a function error

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm following the tutorial here: 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide

I'm sure I've added the `Client Id` and `Javascript Origin` correctly.

But the chart doesn't appear and I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.google.load is not a function

It seems to appear every time I run the `execute()` function

Anyone else run into this problem?

Answer (score 23):

After much tossing and turning, I finally got the answer, all I had to do was add

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

to the application.html.erb file